# iOS project: If I use C++ (C++11) anywhere in my project, must I disable modules?

Tags: c++, ios, xcode

I see the "Use of '@import' when modules are disabled" error even when I switch to YES the "Enable Modules (C and Objective-C)" option in the Build Settings.

A hunch tells me that since my project in fact happens to have many Objective-C++ `.mm` source files, that perhaps this just means that modules (which are not C++ ready yet) simply can't be enabled. Is this true, or am I just missing some other configuration setting?

Answer (score 2):

It says here:

> NOTE: At this time, modules are only available for Apple’s frameworks.
>   and have been implicitly disabled for C++.

Source: http://stoneofarc.wordpress.com/2013/06/25/introduction-to-objective-c-modules/